# Why doesn't my Touch N Go garage door opener lift the door?

Tags: doors, garage

I have a Touch N Go model 100 garage door opener, with a remote and a push-button on the wall.  When I press the opener or the wall button, I hear a click (I'm assuming this is a relay) and then there is a buzzing sound.

There is a 110 plug for the motor and a wall-wart type plug which I assume is the receiver for the remote.

I took the cover off of the unit and disconnected a small plastic box that was attached to the inside of the cover.  It has a white modular type plug.

Question 1: What is this thing?

Now, when I press the button to open the door it clicks and buzzes.  If I go up and give the wheel with the belt on it a manual 1/4 turn or so, the door works fine.  It starts and stops in the correct place, just needs a little help starting.  I'm thinking the problem is either a capacitor or starter motor, but I'm not sure.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone else wants to know:  I went and bought a 330 Volt 54-63 uf capacitor   and installed it.  Not only did I not electrocute myself, I fixed it.

It cost me < $7 - not too bad.